# Web scraping in VBA using getElementsByClassName

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to scrape the price of the product on this page - "https://shop.rema1000.dk/varer/180122" - using VBA (I want a messageBox saying 8.95 or just 8 for a start). I've added Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls to the module and written the following code:

```
Sub Webscraping()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("https://shop.rema1000.dk/varer/180122")

Set ht = ie.document

MsgBox ht.getElementsByClassName("price-normal _38hRkz1ofKt4-Y4OFCHnmh")(0).innerText

End Sub
```

I'm not sure about how to use the getElementsByClassName method, and when I run the code I get error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

What to do?

Comment: You're not waiting for the page to load.   Put a breakpoint on the `Set ht = ...` line, run the sub, and when it hits the breakpoint wait a while to make sure the page is loaded.  Then press F5 to continue  and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: I've tried so. I get error 91 after after the breakpoint, when the MsgBox line is run.

Comment: That URL won't load for me, so there's not much I can suggest.